# In Android imageView wrap_content does not work

Tags: android, imageview

I've got an ImageView with *match_parent* width and *wrap_content* height. When I set an image with a size of 1080x500, the ImageView takes up the entire screen in width, but for some reason takes up extra space in height.I know about AdjustViewbounds, but I'm wondering why imageView takes up extra space in height. I have a Pixel phone (1080x1920).

[here is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHn9L.jpg)

Comment: your image heigh is `wrap_content` so it took it's original height. if you want it to fill the screen, you should set proper `scaleType`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Answer (score 1):

Check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

CENTER_CROP
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image’s aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

CENTER_INSIDE
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image’s aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

FIT_CENTER
Scale the image using Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER

Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER: Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.

FIT_END
Scale the image using Matrix.ScaleToFit.END

Matrix.ScaleToFit.END: Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. END aligns the result to the right and bottom edges of dst.

FIT_START
Scale the image using Matrix.ScaleToFit.START

Matrix.ScaleToFit.START: Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns the result to the left and top edges of dst.

FIT_XY
Scale the image using Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL

Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL: Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.

MATRIX
Scale using the image matrix when drawing.